Why is Apache reverse proxy working from port 443 VirtualHost, but not port 80?
I used a <Macro> to share reverse proxy definitions between two virtual hosts:
<Macro revproxies>
  ProxyPass "/index.html"               "http://internal-webserver/index.html"
  ProxyPassReverse "/index.html"        "http://internal-webserver/index.html"
  # Numerous others
</Macro>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias external-webserver
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.example.com.log combined
  Use revproxies
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias external-webserver
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  SSLEngine on
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.example.com.log combined
  Use revproxies
</VirtualHost>

When I connect via HTTPS to fetch /index.html, I get the correct page from internal-webserver via reverse proxy. When I connect via HTTP to fetch index.html, I get the Apache-generated default welcome page instead; it is not proxying.
The macro is a red herring; even if the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse entries are copy-pasted into the port 80 VirtualHost, they don't work.

It was caused by the following stray line at the top level:
ServerName www.example.com

This caused the main server to intercept these port 80 requests, over the VirtualHost for that same name.
